# Send model from view to controller onchange in mvc razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery, razor

I have the below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {  
       $('#cboDeptID').change(function () {
           var selectedDepartmentId = $(this).val();
           var depmodel = {
            Employees:'@Model.Employees',
            Departments:'@Model.Departments',   
            DepartmentId:'@Model.DepartmentId',
            DepartmentName:'@Model.DepartmentName',               
            SelectedDepartmentId:'@Model.SelectedDepartmentId'               
           };
            $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetEmployees","DepartmentController")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ model: depmodel })
           })
.success(function (result) {
        alert('Success!');})
    .error(function (xhr, status){               alert('The provider could not be updated.');});

        });         
    });
</script>
```

on this combo change i want to pass model to  the controller. The model contains above members such as employees,departments,departmentid etc. The controller action will be fired on combo change but model member values are null. Am I doing it wrong? pls help.

Controller method is as shown below

```
  public ActionResult GetEmployees(DepartmentModel model)
    {
//    code goes here

return View ("DepartmentView",model);
         }
```

Comment: can you show your controller post event..? As i am doing it I am getting the complete model object in my POST event..

Comment: I have added the controller method..

Comment: what is with TicketMaster..?

Comment: its the controller.. I have changed the name to DepartmentController :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your JSON.stringify line to:

```
data: JSON.stringify(depmodel)
```

The automatic model binding when you post this data to the controller is getting confused because you're posting your array of key value pairs (employees, departments etc) inside another array when you call JSON.stringify. So what it's receiving is something like:

```
{ model: { Employees: <value>, ... } }
```

But what it wants is only the key value pairs of the properties inside the model to which it is trying to bind